# Unable to subtract two datetime columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following code:

```
date_today = datetime.datetime.today()
date_today = date_today.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

df = df[['Email','First Name', 'Last Name', 'Newsletter and Caution', 'Interest','Last Contacted','Relationship']]

df['Last Contacted'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Last Contacted'], format='%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S')

df['Last Contacted'] = df['Last Contacted'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

df['Last Contacted'] = df['Last Contacted'].apply(pd.Timestamp)

df['Days since contact'] = (date_today - df['Last Contacted']).dt.days
```

I'm trying to add a column with the numbers of days since last contact obtained by subtracting the last contacted column from today's date.

However I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DatetimeArray' and 'str'
```

The code works perfectly in Jupyter but not in Terminal.

What could be the problem?

Comment: convert `date_today` to timestamp first

Comment: I am doing that in the 4th line as shown in the code above. Is there an alternate method to do that?

Comment: What it `date_today`?

Comment: it is a datetime.datetime.today() variable, added to code

Comment: I got it, I'm converting date_today to a string. Stupid error. Thanks guys.

Comment: your code is not reprodicible. Please read about [mcve](/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi, thanks. I'm new here, wasn't familiar with the rule. Will keep it in mind the next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the culprit:

```
date_today = date_today.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

this is enough to turn `date_today` into a string.

What you want is:

```
date_today = pd.Timestamp(datetime.date.today())
df = df[['Email','First Name', 'Last Name', 'Newsletter and Caution', 'Interest','Last Contacted','Relationship']]

df['Last Contacted'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Last Contacted'], format='%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S')

df['Last Contacted'] = df['Last Contacted'].dt.floor('D')

df['Days since contact'] = (date_today - df['Last Contacted']).dt.days
```

Avoid as much as you can converting datetimes to string to remove parts. On pandas use `floor` for periods not greater than a day, and `to_period` for longer periods.

Answer (score 2):

In your second line :

```
date_today = date_today.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

you cast your datetime into a string.

`strftime` means string from time. 
That is why you have the error when you try to compare your date times with a string in the line :

```
df['Days since contact'] = (date_today - df['Last Contacted']).dt.days
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `pandas` only

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"LastContacted":pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01', freq="6H", periods=20)})

df["DaysSinceLast"] = (pd.datetime.today() - df["LastContacted"]).dt.days
```